# no such file or directory

Tags: qt, path, filenotfoundexception, projects-and-solutions

I am finishing migrating a project from Qt 4.x to 5, but the .pro file is giving me a lot of errors:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHDP
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l../../Qwt/qwt-5.2.0/lib/debug/qwt5
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lqenc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzlibwapi
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lqextserialport
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lqxmpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ljson_lib
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSerialPort1
```

When I comment those lines containing the -lWhatever I get the same errors from other lines below those, at

```
MOC_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles/release
OBJECTS_DIR += release
UI_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles
RCC_DIR = GeneratedFiles
include(Swibz.pri)
```

Here is the full code:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = Swibz
DESTDIR = ../Release
QT += core gui network webkit webkitwidgets xml opengl serialport
CONFIG += release
DEFINES += _WINDOWS QT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT QT_XML_LIB QT_OPENGL_LIB QT_NETWORK_LIB QT_DLL QWT_DLL
INCLUDEPATH += ../../../SprintLib \
    ./GeneratedFiles \
    ./GeneratedFiles/release \
    GeneratedFiles/release \
    . \
    ./../../Qwt/qwt-5.2.0/src \
    ../../../QENC/QENC \
    ../../../zlib-1.2.5 \
    ../../../serial/qextserialport-1.2win-alpha \
    ../../../qxmpp-0.3.0/src \
    ../../../JSON \
    ../../../QtSerialPort/qtserialport/include
LIBS += -L"../../../SprintLib/release" \
    -L"../../../QENC/release" \
    -L"../../../zlib-1.2.5/contrib/vstudio/vc9/x86/ZlibDllRelease" \
    -L"../../../serial/qextserialport-1.2win-alpha/Release" \
    -L" qxmpp-0.3.0/lib" \
    -L"../../../JSON/Release" \
    -L"../../../QtSerialPort/qtserialport/src/serialport/release" \
    -lopengl32 \
    -lglu32 \
    -lgdi32 \
    -luser32 \
    -lHDP \ #cannot find
    -l../../Qwt/qwt-5.2.0/lib/debug/qwt5 \ #cannot find
    -lqenc \ #cannot find
    -lzlibwapi \ #cannot find
    -lqextserialport \ #cannot find
    -lsetupapi \
    -lqxmpp \ #cannot find
    -ljson_lib \ #cannot find
    -lSerialPort1 #cannot find
DEPENDPATH += ./ 
MOC_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles/release #cannot find
OBJECTS_DIR += release #cannot find
UI_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles #cannot find
RCC_DIR = ./GeneratedFiles #cannot find
include(Swibz.pri) #cannot find
#win32:RC_FILE = ./Swibz.rc
TRANSLATIONS = ln_en.ts
TRANSLATIONS = ln_lv.ts
TRANSLATIONS = ln_lt.ts
TRANSLATIONS = ln_es.ts

CODECFORTR     = UTF-8
```

What could it be? I do have the folder GeneratedFiles and release, so I dont know whats wrong.
Also, I dont quite understand the meaning of ./../../ and ./, if anyone could explain to me, maybe I can see easier the issue.

EDIT: Here go more errors I get when I coment the -lthingys, it doesnt make sense

```
g++: error: DEPENDPATH: No such file or directory
g++: error: MOC_DIR: No such file or directory
g++: error: +=: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `./` means current directory: so `./GeneratedFiles` is the directory `GeneratedFiles` where the script is being executed. each `../` means one level up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanations

The usage of the switches are not coherent with the manual of the GCC suite. ([doc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc))

> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library, which is actually a file named liblibrary.a. The linker then uses this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.
>
> The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any that you specify with -L.

There should be only names/filemanes appearing after `-l` switches.

Please also note that if you specify a name and not a filename (with extension), the linker will look for a `lib<name>.(a|so|dll)` file.

#### Example for qxmpp:

You specified `-L" qxmpp-0.3.0/lib"` which adds the `qxmpp-0.3.0/lib` directory (located in the current project directory) to the list of directory to parse when looking for libraries. Then `-lqxmpp` instructs the linker to look within the directory list for a file named `libqxmpp.a`.

### Solving

Therefore, you must check for each not found library that : there is a `-L` directive pointing to the right directory where the library stands (usualy `./` will refer to the root of the project, and `../` its parent directory *etc*), and check that you call for the library with a correct name in a `-l` directive (either the full filemane, or the abbreviated name).

Comment: Perfect! Ill check it out immediatly. Just one thing, what about the DEPENDPATH += ./ and such, they are giving errors but have nothing to do with libraries

Comment: Can't tell since I never had to deal with this yet.

Comment: I commented all the lines that were giving problems and moved the include() to the top of the application. Im getting more erros now but its an advance.